# How does one receive and post text messages on a website, a la Twitter?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, sms

I've looked around at pretty much all the SMS posts here on SO and the best answer I've come up with so far is [ZeepMobile](http://zeepmobile.com). The only problem is, they're <del>"in beta" and aren't readily accepting users</del> no longer in operation. Is there a workaround for this, maybe receiving an email via text (kind of like how [TwitPic](http://www.twitpic.com) does it?) somehow and parsing it?

Basically all I want to do is have people text the site so that their message posts... I don't need to send any messages (actually I would prefer not to). Pretty much the same functionality as Twitter (same functionality, but no I'm not building a Twitter-esque service because I am not crazy).

PS this will be a VB.NET ASP.NET 3.5 solution.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify this question. Do you need people to be able to send SMS messages to your site, or just type short messages in? Do you need the site to be able to send SMS messages, or just store them and maybe display them to other users?

Comment: I need a method for someone to post a string of text to the website via their cellphone.

Comment: i need a method for many someones to post strings of text to the website via their cellphones

Comment: Have you thought of just using twitter for this part of the app, at least to get started?

Their API is well documented, and pretty simple.

Comment: if it were as easy as using twitter i would, but it's not, so i can't. i don't want to just parse a twitter feed. i run http://www.quotidianword.com and i am looking for a solution on how i can get users to post their sentences via cell phone because people aren't always around their comps, but are typically always around their phones. if you take a quick gander at the site, you'll get an idea for what i'm trying to do. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use an SMS gateway service, which is basically a telecom type service which takes text messages and turns them into http (or whatever) requests. There are a number of such services out there other than ZeepMobile if you just do a search on "SMS providers".  (My guess is you're looking for a free provider, which is why you mentioned them)

The bottom line is, you are going to need some other service to interface between your application and the telecom portion.  You can't just write some code and expect text messages to start coming in.

Comment: thanks... i got that part... i was also curious about the email-to-website part, like what twitpic does... maybe that's a solution as well?

Answer (score 0):

I just created an SMS Gateway service. The deployment is not far, so it can be out any moment.

You can install it just as server where you have a windows service running and connecting either with every GSM Modem or Cell Phone as modem (That supports reading incoming messages), best solution for what you want, is an SMSC Provider using SMPP Protocol where is supported too.

While the service is started you can receive SMS Messages into your SQL Server database and from there manipulate as you like. More this is hosting a WCF Service so you can attach your own application and send/receive messages. Also comes with a web based client (Email Client like) ASP.NET 3.5. Supports Mass SMS send too.

This is not an actual advertising but a solution for you i think. 
I sent you over an email too.